# Where does ssh2 for php need to be installed?

Tags: php, pear, pecl

Trying to install ssh2 onto a litespeed server and using the traditional install methods are not working for me. I have successfully installed ssh2 into the /etc/php/cli and it works from the command line. However my litespeed server is using the php.ini from the directory /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/7.4/litespeed/php.ini. I confirmed that by running phpinfo() from the browser and looking at the Loaded Configuration File entry which shows /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php/7.4/litespeed/php.ini. No matter what I try and what examples or steps provided to me, I cannot get it to install in an area that I can use via the browser. I do see this line "/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/50-ssh2.ini," in the Additional .ini files parsed section of the phpinfo() page however no matter what I have tried, I cannot get it so show up like its installed when I view the phpinfo() page.

Answer (score 0):

This works for LSPHP81 with SSH2, feel free to replace the PHP version with your current version.

1 - Install necessary PHP packages and ssh2 lib

```
apt-get update
apt-get install lsphp81-pear lsphp81-dev -y
apt-get install libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev -y
```

2 - Download SSH2 package from pecl

```
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.3.1.tgz
tar -zxvf ssh2-1.3.1.tgz
cd ssh2-1.3.1
```

3 - Compile ssh2 package

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/phpize
./configure --with-ssh2=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81 --with-php-config=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/php-config
make
make install
echo "extension=ssh2.so" >> /usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/ssh2.ini
```

4 - Reload lsws and PHP

```
systemctl restart lsws
killall lsphp
```

5 - Result
[image]