# How to install PHP Extension php-ssh2 on Azure App Service (PHP 8.2 / Linux)?

Tags: php, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, debian

Does anyone know how to install the PHP extension "php-ssh2" on an Azure App Service with PHP version 8.2 and Linux OS?

I tried installing the extension from a different repository, but unfortunately this does not work ([Not candidate version]).

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `I tried installing the extension from a different repository, but unfortunately this does not work ` from where you have tried? Have you tried in Kudu - SSH/Bash

Comment: Please check this [SOthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634174/where-does-ssh2-for-php-need-to-be-installed) once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the below steps to install the `SSH2` extension in `Azure Linux App Service`.**

Open the `KUDU` Console:

```cs
https://YourApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
```

[image]

***My PHP Version:***

[image]

- Run the below command to install the SSH2 version.

```cs
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libssh2-1-dev
```

[image]

- Run `pear config-show` command to see the paths of the directories.

[image]

- Run
  `pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.4.tgz` command to install the ssh2 zip file.
- You can see the downloaded `ssh2` file in `/tmp/pear/download` directory
- Next run the below commands

```cs
cd  /tmp/pear/download/
tar -xzf ssh2-1.4.tgz
cd ssh2-1.4
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

[image]

- Now you can see modules folder is created in `/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-1.4` directory.
- modules folder contains the `ssh2.so` file.

[image]

- Now we need to move this file from download to   extension  folder `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829` folder

```cs
mv /tmp/pear/download/ssh2-1.4/modules/ssh2.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829
```

[image]

- Run the `php -m` to check the extensions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply @Harshitha

Everything is fine, until the step "Run pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.4.tgz command to install the ssh2 zip file."

It asks me "libssh2 prerfix? [autodetect] : "  After which I have to fill in something. When I just hit enter, it is checking for lots of things, but then at the bottom it says: 

make: *** [Makefile:210: ssh2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: After that, when continuing with the next steps, the modules folder is empty and I cannot see the file ssh2.so in it. I guess it has to do with the above error?

Comment: When running php -v now it says:



Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Have you checked the ssh2 tgz folder ` /tmp/pear/download/` in downloads folder?

Comment: @Harshitha when going to the /tmp/pear/download folder I see the following items in the download folder: imagick-3.7.0.tgz  mongodb-1.16.2.tgz  package.xml  pdo_sqlsrv-5.11.1.tgz  redis-6.0.1.tgz  sqlsrv-5.11.1.tgz  ssh2-1.4  ssh2-1.4.tgz

Comment: Ok .. yes this is correct

Comment: You need to run the commands Starting from tar..in download folder

Comment: When executing the command "Run pecl install pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.4.tgz", what do I have to fill in at the "libssh2 prefix? [autodetect] : "? Do I have to leave it blank and hit enter? Or do I have to fill in something?

Comment: Even if make install fails .. the ssh2.so will be available in downloads folder.Final step is to move that to extensions folder.

Comment: Fill yes.. in prefix

Comment: After filling in "yes" in prefix I get the same as before. It continues, but at the end it shows the following error: 
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:210: ssh2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: The ssh2.so is not available for me in the downloads folder

Comment: Have you done this `cd  /tmp/pear/download/
tar -xzf ssh2-1.4.tgz
cd ssh2-1.4
phpize
./configure`

Comment: Please follow the steps correctly step by step

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Those steps are successfully executed without any issues. I followed the steps step by step.

It is just that the ss2.so is not there.

Comment: Are you perhaps able to help me out through Teamviewer or Microsoft Teams? Or do you have any other suggestions what the issue could be?

Comment: Ssh2.so will be available in `tmp/pear/download/ssh2-1.4/modules` folder.run `cd /tmp/pear/download/ssh2-1.4/modules` and check

Comment: /tmp/pear/download/ssh2-1.4/modules# ls -all
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 21 13:18 ..

Comment: The above is all that I see. Unfortunately there is no ssh2.so in the modules folder

Comment: Something is missing from your side.

Comment: When running a php -v, it shows the following warning:

Comment: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Run `pear config-show` and check the paths of extensions and downloads folders.May be your path is different.

Comment: I ran the command and the paths are exactly the same. Also when running this command I get the same as above: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/ssh2.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Harshitha I figured it out. After the ./configure command, I executed the command "make". After this, the ssh2.so has been created and can now be located in the modules folder. When running php -m, I can now see ssh2 under the PHP modules. Do I have to restart PHP in order to load the newly installed extension?

Comment: Have you completed all the steps now?Is the issue resolved.

Comment: As I remember I haven't done any restart.Check as it ..is if not working then u restart.

Comment: You need to copy from module to extensions folder ..have you done that?

Comment: I think I have completed it yes. I copied from module to extensions folder. /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829# php -m

When I run this command I can see ssh2 under PHP modules.

Comment: On the website's PHP info (AppName.azurewebsites.net/phpinfo.php) I cannot see the ssh2 table. Is that normal?

Comment: It has to show..Even Iam not sure about that.. need to check.

Comment: Restart the app and check once.

Comment: Refer this  [SoThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478844/how-do-i-see-the-extensions-loaded-by-php) once

Comment: Or may be the version we have installed is not compatible with installed PHP version.

Comment: When I run "php -i", I can see the following regarding ssh: ssh2

SSH2 support => enabled
extension version => 1.4
libssh2 version => 1.9.0
banner => SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.9.0